# Change Ankhsvn diff behavior

Tags: visual-studio-2008, diff, ankhsvn

I want to have the diff results window show in the task bar, instead of being a floating visual studio dialog item.  Can I do this?

Comment: According to http://johnnycoder.com/blog/2008/07/22/getting-started-with-ankhsvn/ (QuickStart section 3) you can specify an external diff tool via Tools > Options > Source Control > Subversion.  That's not showing for me, but maybe you'll have more luck...

Comment: It's under Tools > Options > Source Control > Subversion User Tools for me.

Comment: Just a side note, but to control whether those VS diff windows float, in the "Subversion User Tools" settings page, you can check the "Create Visual Studio Diff/Merge documents floating" option. Having this disabled can be problematic because in some situations the diff window can be docked **behind modal dialogs** (like when you open a diff from a Commit window in an integrated tool like AnkhSvn), making it totally unusable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to `Tools > Options > Source Control > Subversion User Tools` to see what Diff/Merge tools are supported.

Download your favorite merge tool (if you didn't already do that for other purposes). My favorite is SourceGear DiffMerge.

Go to the configuration page again, and select your tool from the drop down. It'll be automatically detected by AnkhSvn

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have for Visual Studio 2008.  It failed to detect my installation of 64-bit Araxis on Win7x64.

External Diff Tool:

```
 "$(HostProgramFiles)\Araxis\Araxis Merge\compare.exe" /max /wait  "$(Base)" "$(Mine)" /title1:"$(BaseName)" /title2:"$(MineName)"
```

Haven't tried with VS2010 yet.

This *should* be the command for Merging, but I haven't tested it yet:

```
"$(HostProgramFiles)\Araxis\Araxis Merge\compare.exe" /a2 /max /wait /3 /title1:"$(TheirName)" /title2:"$(BaseName)" /title3:"$(MineName)" "$(Theirs)" "$(Base)" "$(Mine)" "$(Merged)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer VS2010 diffmerge tool. You can set it for compare and merge easily.

For External Diff Tool:

```
"$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\diffmerge.exe" "$(Base)" "$(Mine)"
```

External Merge Tool:

```
"$(ProgramFiles)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\diffmerge.exe" /merge $(Theirs) $(Mine) $(Base) $(Merged)
```

And luckily it appears on Taskbar.